# How to use a custom function with an ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, custom-function

I want to write a function that can be used inside an ArrayFormula. My table is like this:

```
 | A | B | C |
1| a |   |   |
2| b |   |   |
3| c |   |   |
```

First I wrote a simple function to return the input (so I know it works inside the ArrayFormula):

```
function retAddress(cell){
  return cell;
}
```

On B1 I wrote `=ArrayFormula(retAddress(address(row(B:B),column(A:A),4)))` and apparently it worked as expected, it returned each address, like this:

```
 | A | B | C |
1| a | A1|   |
2| b | A2|   |
3| c | A3|   |
```

Now, on column C, I wanted to return the values of column A, so I wrote a function like this:

```
function retValue(cell){
  var cellRang = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell);
  return cellRang.getValue();
}
```

And on C1 I wrote `=ArrayFormula(retValue(address(row(B:B),column(A:A),4)))` but it gives me error `Exception: Range not found (line 2).`, which is the line with `getRange(cell)` method.

If I write the function without ArrayFormula like this:

On C1, `=retValue(address(row(C1),column(A:A),4))`

On C2, `=retValue(address(row(C2),column(A:A),4))`

On C3, `=retValue(address(row(C3),column(A:A),4))`

I get the expected result:

```
 | A | B | C |
1| a | A1| a |
2| b | A2| b |
3| c | A3| c |
```

So, how to make it work in ArrayFormula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell)
```

`cell` is array if you provide a array input. `getRange` method expects a single string as input.

#### Solution:

- `map` the array to single value

#### References:

- [Custom Function#Optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)
- [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use-batch-operations)

#### Snippet#1:

```
function retValue(cell){
  if(cell.map) {
    return cell.map(retValue);
  } else {
    var cellRang = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell);
    return cellRang.getValue();
  }
}
```

#### Snippet#2:

Note that in the previous snippet you're calling `getValue()` 1 time per each cell in the input array. This is extremely slow. Better way is to call it as a batch:

```
=retValues("A1:B4")
```

```
function retValues(cell){//modified
  var cellRang = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell);
  return cellRang.getValues();//modified
}
```

- Note that:

  - Only 1 call to `getValues()` is made.
  - Formula returns a array without explicit use of `=ARRAYFORMULA()`. All custom formulas are by default, array formulas, but they need to be configured to return values as  arrays in apps script.

Comment: Snippet 1 kinda of solves the problem although it  is very slow as you pointed out. For snippet 2 I have to enter "A1:B4" as input, but if I copy the formula to another cell it doesn' t update it as it is a string. So, instead of entering `=retValues("A1:B4")`, how do I enter `=retValues(A1:B4)`, without quotes?

Comment: @Adriano  Your `retAddress` should work fine. What's wrong with `=retAddress(A1:B4)` or just `=arrayformula(a1:b4)`? I added the quotes, because you wanted to provide the result of `=ADDRESS()` ,a string to script. If you still have issues, Kindly ask a new question with enough details.

Comment: My point is that passing as input A1:B4 will actually pass the values of those cells in a 2 dimensional array, but not the address itself, that's why I've been using `=address()`. But you answer worked fine with `=ArrayFormula()` and `=address()`, so thank you.